# Bazel build missing strict dependencies

Tags: go, github, build, dependencies, bazel

I am trying to build a Go application with brazel. It is an existing private GitHub repo (with this location: `github.xyz.com/repo-name`) that I am working on, and my aim is to create a binary out of a main.go file that depends on some other Go files for it's methods. This is my BUILD.bazel file inside the folder called e2e where all these go files are present:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")

go_binary(
    name = "e2e",
    embed = [":go_default_library"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = ["main.go"],
    data = [
        "//cmd/iasd",
        "//migrations:migration_files",
        "//test/iamd:client-ca-bundle.pem",
    ] + glob(
        ["testdata/**"],
    ),
    importpath = "github.xyz.com/repo-name/test/e2e",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//test:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/go/tools/bazel:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/database/cockroachdb:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/source/file:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/google/uuid:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/lib/pq:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/pkg/errors:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/google.golang.org/grpc:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials:go_default_library",
        "//api/grpc/v1/applications:go_default_library",
        "//api/grpc/v1/clients:go_default_library",
        "//pkg/oauth2/mtls:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/coreos/go-oidc:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go:go_default_library",
        "//vendor/golang.org/x/oauth2:go_default_library",
    ],
)
```

and this is how the imports look in my main.go file:

```
import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/coreos/go-oidc"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.xyz.com/repo-name/api/grpc/v1/applications"
    "github.xyz.com/repo-name/api/grpc/v1/clients"
    "github.xyz.com/repo-name/pkg/oauth2/mtls"
    "github.xyz.com/repo-name/test/e2e"
    "github.xyz.com/repo-name/test"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)
```

Now on executing the command `bazel run //test/e2e:e2e`, I get the following error:

```
compilepkg: missing strict dependencies:
    /private/var/tmp/_bazel_<myname>/a9b32769d59e90b5398bc5d8a988c877/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/394/execroot/github_xyz_com_repo_name/test/e2e/main.go: import of "github.xyz.com/repo-name/test/e2e"
No dependencies were provided.
```

This is because of the import `github.xyz.com/repo-name/test/e2e` in my main file. To include the import, if I add this to my BUILD.bazel file in deps: `"//test/e2e:go_default_library"` it ends up with this error:

```
"//test/e2e:go_default_library: cycle in dependency graph:
    //test/e2e:e2e
.-> //test/e2e:go_default_library [self-edge]"
```

I understand the context of errors, but I cannot figure out a suitable way to resolve it. What changes should I make in my BUILD.bazel file to get include the dependency correctly?

Comment: I’m not very familiar with Bazel itself, but, reading through the README, it recommends that you have a BUILD.bazel file for each pkg that contains go code. It looks like `test/e2e` is a sub package of `e2e`. Is it possible that you need to add another BUILD.bazel file for that sub package?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Not only was I required to add a BUILD.bazel file for the sub package, but  I also added my main file in a new folder inside the e2e folder (while keeping the helper files in the e2e folder). This way when I added a dependency of my main.go file to the helper files, it did not lead to a cyclic dependency error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding my main.go file in a new folder inside the e2e folder (while keeping the helper files in the e2e folder). This way when I added a dependency of my main.go file to the helper files, it did not lead to a cyclic dependency error.