# Getting missing strict dependencies error when trying to build with Bazel

Tags: go, build, bazel

I'm trying to run `bazel build //cmd/todo:todo` on this repo https://github.com/a8m/ent-graphql-example that I had initialized as a Bazel project but I'm gettting this error:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //cmd/todo:todo (138 packages loaded, 1651 targets configured).
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/eff35caf342d5b1674cee7da49b4c5b3/external/io_ariga_atlas/sql/migrate/BUILD.bazel:3:11: GoCompilePkg external/io_ariga_atlas/sql/migrate/migrate.a failed: (Exit 1): builder failed: error executing GoCompilePkg command (from target @@io_ariga_atlas//sql/migrate:migrate) bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-ST-13d3ddad9198/bin/external/go_sdk/builder_reset/builder compilepkg -sdk external/go_sdk -installsuffix linux_amd64 -src external/io_ariga_atlas/sql/migrate/dir.go -src ... (remaining 27 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
compilepkg: missing strict dependencies:
        /tmp/bazel-working-directory/_main/external/io_ariga_atlas/sql/migrate/dir.go: import of "slices"
        /tmp/bazel-working-directory/_main/external/io_ariga_atlas/sql/migrate/migrate.go: import of "slices"
No dependencies were provided.
Check that imports in Go sources match importpath attributes in deps.
Target //cmd/todo:todo failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.508s, Critical Path: 0.74s
INFO: 70 processes: 18 internal, 52 linux-sandbox.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I was wondering how I might be able to resolve this issue. I checked [Bazel build missing strict dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622610/bazel-build-missing-strict-dependencies) but I'm already seeing that the file structure matches what was used by the OP in the other post, except I'm getting the same error. Thanks!